# Write only two characters after "."?

Tags: c#

In textbox after this character "." I want the user to put in only 2 characters something like this
`100.00`. How can i do that ?

Comment: ASP.NET, Winforms or WPF? In any case, a masked textbox probably is the best solution.

Comment: -1 Agree with Daniel, it's important to know which technology you're using. On the other side knowing what have you tried is usefulness to us to answer your question.

Comment: You are asking a question similar to [[Textbox display formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671148/textbox-display-formatting)]

Answer (score 2):

Implement the [OnTextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.ontextchanged.aspx) event to limit and modify content

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int i = textBox1.Text.IndexOf(".");
     if ((i != -1) && (i == textBox1.Text.Length - 4))
     {
         textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, textBox1.Text.Length - 1);
         textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
     }
}
```

Comment: A summary would make this a much better answer, as it stands its usefulness relies wholly on the linked site, content of which we have no control over.

Comment: @RhysW Summary of what? of the documentation?

Comment: A summarry of using it to solve the problem, why its useful, and perhaps an example implementation. The more information thats given in a clear context the better the answer and the more useful it will potentially be to future people facing this issue under slightly different terms

Comment: As the solution is allready provided i will post it, but in general i'm against providing solutions, i prefer providing the idea, it helps to learn coding much more than a copy paste solutions.

Comment: Some people, myself included, learn better visually, for  example once i see a solution it is much easier to understand and to manipulate into a range of different solutions for future use and to grasp a new concept

Answer (score 1):

if your goal is only numbers use:

winforms
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.aspx

wpf
[Good NumericUpDown equivalent in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382676/good-numericupdown-equivalent-in-wpf)

asp.net
http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/NumericUpDown/NumericUpDown.aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can check the length of the textbox.text after the point, to do it.
find the index of '.' and then if textbox.text.length is bigger than that index + 3 delete the last letter.

```
int indexofDot=textbox.Text.indexOf('.');
if(textbox.text.Length>indexofDot+3) {... }
```

to delete the last letter just copy the string to onther temp string and delete the last char
and then return it to textbox.Text

Answer (score 0):

You can use it's [`TextChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.textchanged.aspx) event to validate the input:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
    double d;
    if (!double.TryParse(txt.Text, out d))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number");
        return;
    }

    string num = d.ToString();
    string decSeparator = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator;
    int numDecPlaces = 0;
    int decSepIndex = num.LastIndexOf(decSeparator);
    if (decSepIndex != -1)
        numDecPlaces = num.Substring(decSepIndex).Length;
    if (numDecPlaces > 2)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter two decimal places at a maximum");
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to determine whether you functionally want to:

- **Prevent** i.e. by using a mask,  or
- **Validate** i.e. by using a regular expression

The implementations vary based on the chosen technology.

When you choose to prevent, you can look for a [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx) control. It is provided in WinForms and can be found on the web for WPF.

When you choose to validate, use the best practises for either [Windows Forms](http://blog.scosby.com/post/2010/02/11/Validation-in-Windows-Forms.aspx) of [WPF](http://weblogs.asp.net/monikadyrda/archive/2009/06/24/wpf-textbox-validation.aspx).