# Override OnEnter to disable formatting onenter text but breaks Data Binding

Tags: c#, data-binding, formatting

```
public class CustomTextBox
{

    protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
    {

        if (this.DataBindings.Count > 0)
        {
            this.cancelvalidating = true;
            this.DataBindings[0].FormattingEnabled = false;
            this.cancelvalidating = false;
        }

        OldText = this.Text;
        base.OnEnter(e);
    }

    protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.DataBindings.Count > 0)
        {
            this.cancelvalidating = true;
            this.DataBindings[0].FormattingEnabled = true;
            this.cancelvalidating = false;
        }
        base.OnLeave(e);
    }


}
```

When you enter the binded textbox format should disappear and on leave should the text again formatted. When I try this code databinding breaks.

Comment: You should ask a specific question after adding some relevant context in the post itself. It's not immediately clear what you expect others to help you out with. Consider reading the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: i think my question is very clear if not i could try again. I have a form with databindings now some of textbox are representing price so these textboxes are rounded (formatted) two decimal. Now when i Enter these textboxes i want that format removes. example 2,4565 is rounded to 2.46 when i now enter this textbox it should be 2,4565 (formatting off). I hope this time it was clear enough.Thanks [Alarmsystemen](http://www.ramcom.be/beveiliging/alarmsystemen)

Comment: Consider doing the opposite of what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671148/textbox-display-formatting) recommends.