# format a currency value when the user is typing any amount of cash in textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

What is the best way to automatically format a currency value when the user is typing any amount of cash?

For Example I have a TextBox, if the user types "30" it considers 0.30 
if he types "300" it considers 3.00.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Textbox display formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671148/textbox-display-formatting)

Comment: What UI framework are you working with? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Option1: build a custom control and listen to the keydown event. Option2: Have a separate hidden textbox control at the backend. Whenever the display textbox got focus just pass the input focus to that hidden box and do your logic there

Answer (score 0):

Make a textbox and handle it in the `TextChanged` event

```
<TextBox x:Name="money" Text="00.00" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
```

and code

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (money.Text.Length == 3)
        {
            money.TextChanged -= TextBox_TextChanged;
            money.Text = money.Text.Replace("00.", "00.0");
            money.CaretIndex = money.Text.Length;
            money.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
        }
        if (money.Text.Length == 1)
        {
            money.TextChanged -= TextBox_TextChanged;
            if(money.Text.Contains(".")) money.Text = money.Text.Replace(".", "");
            money.Text = money.Text.Insert(0, "00.0");
            money.CaretIndex = money.Text.Length;
            money.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
        }
        else if (money.Text.StartsWith("00.0") && money.Text.Length == 6)
        {
            money.TextChanged -= TextBox_TextChanged;
            money.Text = money.Text.Replace("00.0", "00.");
            money.CaretIndex = money.Text.Length;
            money.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
        }
        else if (money.Text.StartsWith("00.") && money.Text.Length == 6)
        {
            money.TextChanged -= TextBox_TextChanged;
            money.Text = money.Text.Replace("00.", "0");
            money.Text = money.Text.Insert(money.Text.Length - 2, ".");
            money.CaretIndex = money.Text.Length;
            money.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
        }
        else if (money.Text.StartsWith("0") && money.Text.Length == 6)
        {
            money.TextChanged -= TextBox_TextChanged;
            money.Text = money.Text.Replace("0", "");
            if(money.Text.Contains(".")) money.Text = money.Text.Replace(".", "");
            money.Text = money.Text.Insert(money.Text.Length - 2, ".");
            money.CaretIndex = money.Text.Length;
            money.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
        }
        else if(!money.Text.StartsWith("0"))
        {
            money.TextChanged -= TextBox_TextChanged;
            if (money.Text.Length == 3 && money.Text.Contains(".")) money.Text = money.Text.Insert(0, "00");
            if(money.Text.Length == 4 && money.Text.Contains(".")) money.Text = money.Text.Insert(0, "0");
            if(money.Text.Length == 1 && !money.Text.Contains(".")) money.Text = money.Text.Insert(0, "00.0");
            if(money.Text.Length == 2 && !money.Text.Contains(".")) money.Text = money.Text.Insert(0, "00.");
            if (money.Text.Length == 3 && !money.Text.Contains(".")) money.Text = money.Text.Insert(0, "0");

            if (money.Text.Contains(".")) money.Text = money.Text.Replace(".", "");
            money.Text = money.Text.Insert(money.Text.Length - 2, ".");
            money.CaretIndex = money.Text.Length;
            money.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
        }
        else
        {
            money.TextChanged -= TextBox_TextChanged;
            if (money.Text.Length == 3 && money.Text.Contains(".")) money.Text = money.Text.Insert(0, "00");
            if (money.Text.Length == 4 && money.Text.Contains(".")) money.Text = money.Text.Insert(0, "0");
            if (money.Text.Length == 1 && !money.Text.Contains(".")) money.Text = money.Text.Insert(0, "00.0");
            if (money.Text.Length == 2 && !money.Text.Contains(".")) money.Text = money.Text.Insert(0, "00.");
            if (money.Text.Length == 3 && !money.Text.Contains(".")) money.Text = money.Text.Insert(0, "0");
            if (money.Text.Contains(".")) money.Text = money.Text.Replace(".", "");
            money.Text = money.Text.Insert(money.Text.Length - 2, ".");
            money.CaretIndex = money.Text.Length;
            money.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
        }
    }
```